# Loop through a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a column in excel using VBA, am having a problem because has "W2" hard coded in the function so as I iterate through the spreadsheet, the W2 needs to change to W3, W4 W5 etc.

below is my code.

```
Function GetTopDrTS(L_NumCellsFromEdge As Integer, L_NumOfCells As Integer) As Double
  'Get Top Drive Side Triple Spot calculation

  Dim val As Double
  val = 0

  'Select Cell W2 to set starting position
  Range("W2").Select

  'Read in the cells we need to average
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To L_NumOfCells - 1
    val = val + Selection.Worksheet.Cells(Selection.Row, _
                Selection.Column + EdgePos + L_NumCellsFromEdge + i).Value
  Next i

  GetTopDrTS = val / L_NumOfCells

end function
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to loop at all.  Your function is just calculating an average, so use the Average function instead.  That reduces your function to one line:

```
Function GetTopDrTS(L_NumCellsFromEdge As Integer, L_NumOfCells As Integer) As Double

    GetTopDrTS = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("W2:W" & L_NumOfCells + 1))

End Function
```

Now that it's exactly one line, I'd get rid of the function entirely and just use the WorksheetFunction anywhere you'd normally call `GetTopDrTS`.

Note that it isn't clear from the question or the code what `EdgePos` and `L_NumCellsFromEdge` are supposed to be - if they are intended to replace the hard-coded column "W", it would be fairly easy to replace it with an offset.

Comment: That's only going to give me an average of w2, however i wanna be able to get the average W2, w3,+ .... + w1326. maybe i should post my entire code

Comment: @BobbyJalloh - No, it will give the average of whatever range it generates based on the input parameter `L_NumOfCells`.  If you `L_NumOfCells = 100`, it evaluates to `WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("W2:W101"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  'Read in the cells we need to average
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To L_NumOfCells - 1
    range("W" & i).select
    val = val + Selection.Worksheet.Cells(Selection.Row, _
                Selection.Column + EdgePos + L_NumCellsFromEdge + i).Value
  Next i
```

Comment: did you mean range("W2" & i).select  ?

Comment: No, I didn't. `Range("W2")` is a hard coded reference to a single cell, and that's what's causing your code to not loop. `Range("W" & i)` removes the hard coded row number and replaces it with the variable `i` which is changed each time through your loop. `Range("W2" & i)` would also be not hard coded, but would give you rows `21-29`, then `210-299`, then `2100-2199`, etc, as `i` increments - probably not what you're after. Give it a try, see what happens, then step through the code in the debugger (hit the `F8` key) to execute one line at a time & see what cell is being selected.